# Run basic administrative commands on GoDaddy

Tags: command-line, administration, vps

I've logged into my GoDaddy server through PuTTY, I'm connected as ted67942 which is not the root user. I'm trying to run basic commands like `sudo`, `dpkg`, `su`, etc. but they all return the "command not found" error. How do I either fix this or log in as the root user? I'm trying to install mod_reqtimeout on my webserver

`echo $PATH` returns the following:
`/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/ted67942/.local/bin:/home/ted67942/bin`

Comment: Can you give us the output of the command `echo $PATH` please ?

Comment: +Thomas Gros It's a bit long. edited question to include it

Comment: What's the output of: `groups`  ... and also `type su`

Comment: It might not be possible to log as  root user on shared server

Comment: groups - "ted67942"
type su - "-bash: type: su: not found"

Comment: As pointed out by @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, you seem to have a user on a shared server. This certainly explains why you don't have access to utilites such as `sudo` and the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy seems to provide a somewhat restricted environment which does not include unlimited root access.

According to GoDaddy documentation, the WebHost Manager (WHM) GUI includes a feature called "EasyApache (Apache Update)".

Within EasyApache, select the gear icon ("Customize Profile"), then "Next Step" and "Exhaustive Options List". There will be a list of Apache and PHP modules that can be added to Apache configuration in GoDaddy's environment. This is probably the only way to add Apache modules in GoDaddy's environment, because it ensures that only modules that are deemed acceptable by GoDaddy can be used.

If `mod_reqtimeout` is not listed there, you should probably contact GoDaddy's support and describe your needs.