# sudo: command not found on cPanel

Tags: ssh, sudo, cpanel, pagespeed

I have a webserver with cPanel, and I tried to install mod-pagespeed. but when use the commands in every tutorial, I get

```
permissions denied
```

and when I use sudo I get

```
bash: sudo commando not found.
```

Somebody know what's happening?

I connect with my server by ssh.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cPanel, but it's possible that you have a restricted VM; relating in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410267/117549

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual for sudo not to be installed, but it may simply not be in your Path. Try `/usr/bin/sudo command`.

If no `sudo` command available, then you need to use the `su` command but it does not work the same as sudo.

Comment: Unusual? Many Linux distributions beyond the beginner friendly ones do not install sudo by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

/bin/sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
/sbin/sudo
/usr/sbin/sudo
/usr/local/bin/sudo
/usr/local/sbin/sudo

In the mean time, good luck finding that missing commando! ;)